# How to get selected values of checkbox list

Tags: jquery

I have a check box list

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="ddrCustomer">
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and bind as

```
ddrCustomer.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
 ddrCustomer.DataTextField = "Customer";
 ddrCustomer.DataValueField = "Id";
 ddrCustomer.DataBind();
 ddrCustomer.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "All"));
```

then Rendered HTML is:

```
   <tr>
     <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="ddrCustomer$1" id="ddrCustomer_1">
          <label for="ddrCustomer_1">10 Manhattan Ave, Storage</label>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

when i call below java script function

```
  $("#ddrCustomer").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {

      alert($(this).val());

    });
```

then it always return `"on"` as checked check boxes values.
I need to bind valus

Comment: That's because you filter out the ones that are checked.

Comment: can you share the generate html of the checkbox element

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ddrCustomer").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {

alert($(this).val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>.aspx Markup</kbd>

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ddrCustomer" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Sam" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

<kbd>Rendered HTML</kbd>

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ctl00$MainContent$ddrCustomer$0"  
               id="MainContent_ddrCustomer_0">
<label for="MainContent_ddrCustomer_0">Sam</label>
```

<kbd>jQuery</kbd>

```
$("#<%= ddrCustomer.ClientID %>").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {

alert(this.checked); // returns checked or not
alert(this.value); //returns value
alert($(this).next('label').text(); // returns SAM. Text value

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
 $("#ddrCustomer").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```